# Is the ETH Zurich part of the University of Zurich?

Tags: university, switzerland

I'm wondering if the ETH Zurich is part of the University of Zurich. Not only are they build close together, according to Google there are famous graduates of the ETH that are also listed as graduates of the University of Zurich(for example Einstein). I couldn't find an answer on neither of their websites.

Comment: No, it is not. Actually, UZH was forked off of ETH 100 years ago. In practice, there is substantial collaboration between the institutions, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some quotes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETH_Zurich):

> ETH is a federal institute (i.e., under direct administration by the Swiss government), whereas the University of Zürich is a cantonal institution. […] In the beginning, both universities were co-located in the buildings of the University of Zürich.
>
> […]
>
> Events of the neighboring University of Zürich are well-attended by ETH students and vice versa.
>
> […]
>
> The amicable rivalry between ETH and the neighbouring University of Zürich has been cultivated since 1951 […]